# tallying elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I'm trying to tally the elements of an array.  By this I mean, I have a large array, and each element will have multiples of itself throughout the array.  I am trying to figure out how many times each element occurs,  however I keep running into the issue of there being duplicate tallies.  Since "x" could exist at 12 different places in the array, when I loop through it and keep a running sum, I get the tally for "x" 12 different times.  Does anyone know of a simpler/better way to keep a tally of an array with no duplicates?

My code is:

where count is the number of elements

```
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {


            for(x=0; x<count;x++)
            {
                    if(array[i]==array[x])
                    {
                            tallyz++;
                    }   

            }

                    tally[i]=tallyz-1;
                    tallyz=0;
                    }

    }
```

Comment: Why not just get rid of `tallyz` and just `tally[i]++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can sort the array, simply sort it. Then all you have left is a linear scan of the elements, checking if the element behind this one is the same as the current element (don't forget bounds checking).

Comment: And if you can't sort the array, make a copy of it and sort the copy.

Comment: the only issue that I forgot to mention is, the array "array" has to be parallel to the tally array in order for me to keep the tally of that element.  So if I were to just sort the tally array than it wouldn't correspond to it's element in the other array. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: If that's the case, use a pair<data_type, int>. Set the int to the integer coordinate of the item in the original array. Then sort the pair based on the first data type. This way you retain your original positions

Answer (score 2):

```
std::map<X, unsigned> tally;

for(i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    ++tally[array[i]];
```

Note that this is best if the redundancy in the array is fairly high.  If most items are unique you're probably better just sorting the array as others have mentioned.

Comment: With this keep the tally array in correspondence with the "array" array?  If it wasn't clear, "array" is of type string and represents something that I'm keeping the tally of so I can't just sort the tallies because it would then throw off what they are connected to.

Comment: @Sam - Using a map assures that there are no duplicates. That was at least **one** of the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to sorting, you could use a map:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
void printSums(T (array&)[N]) {
  map<T, size_t> m;
  for(T*p = array; p < array+N; ++p) {
    ++m[*p];
  }
  for(map<T,size_t>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
  }
}
```

Warning: this is untested code.

Answer (score 0):

first use a map just as John said,then traverse the tally array:

---

```
std::map<X, unsigned> data;

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    data[array[i]]++;

for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    tally[i]=data[tally[i]]-1;
```